# How to prevent httpd on DSM 5.0/Synology DS214 to remove errornous config files?

Tags: nas, apache-http-server, synology

I'm trying to set up some `Rewrite*` directives for a `httpd` 2.2.27 on DSM 5.0 on a Synology DS214 by adding `dokuwiki.conf` to `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled-user` which is included in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. When I restart the web server user instance in the web frontend by de- and reactivating `WebStation` and `personal website`, the config file is simply deleted, no logging entries and thus no change to debug. Before I deal with the errors I'd like to make it right from the beginning and get rid of this behavior of DSM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like all files created by the user in `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled-user` are deleted if they contain errors (syntax errors as well as references to inexisting files (log file, SSL certificates, etc.)) and `httpd` is restarted in the web fronted (by de- and reactivating the `WebStation`.

Solution: put custom configuration files for `httpd` with `.conf` suffix in a separate directory, e.g. `/etc/httpd/sites-enabled-user-custom` and include them by adding

```
include sites-enabled-user-custom/*.conf
```

at the buttom of `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf-user`